# Mercure/Symfony: Authorization Error with JWT Key

Tags: symfony, jwt, mercure

I am using mercure from the symfony binary. After setting up a new project via

```
symfony new mercure
cd mercure
symfony composer req make mercure annotations
symfony console make:controller
symfony server:start
```

I write some minimal code into the newly created controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Mercure\HubInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mercure\Update;

class MainController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="main")
     */
    public function index(HubInterface $hub): Response
    {
        $update = new Update(
            'http://mercure/asdf',
            json_encode(['message' => 'heyo']),
        );
        $hub->publish($update);

        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'Welcome to your new controller!',
            'path' => 'src/Controller/MainController.php',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then, I generate an JWT key from [here](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJtZXJjdXJlIjp7InB1Ymxpc2giOlsiKiJdfX0.iHLdpAEjX4BqCsHJEegxRmO-Y6sMxXwNATrQyRNt3GY) (linked from the symfony documentation) and enter `!ChangeMe!` in the bottom right, as this is the key used by the symfony binary. The JWT key is then set in `.env`:

```
MERCURE_URL=https://127.0.0.1:8000/.well-known/mercure
MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL=https://127.0.0.1:8000/.well-known/mercure
MERCURE_JWT_SECRET=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJtZXJjdXJlIjp7InB1Ymxpc2giOlsiKiJdfX0.obDjwCgqtPuIvwBlTxUEmibbBf0zypKCNzNKP7Op2UM
```

After restarting the server and going to `localhost:8000`, I get `Failed to send an update.` and `HTTP/2 401 returned for "https://localhost:8000/.well-known/mercure".`, which is probably because the key doesn't work correctly. Error on server: `MERCUR Topic selectors not matched, not provided or authorization error`

By setting `MERCURE_JWT_SECRET="!ChangeMe!"` (without encryption), it does work if the site is visited from the machine the server runs on, but from no other machine in the same network (via 192.168.XXX.XXX:8000).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it was a problem with the configuration on my operating system. After pushing the project onto another machine, everything worked fine.

Comment: Same issue and same solution. Thank you! :))